# To do Spring MVC Framework , Eclipse indigo is enough to do the project based Spring MVC?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to Spring MVC Framework,I'm trying to learn Spring MVC using Many Tutorials in Internet.In those tutorials, they use different Plugins and different folder structures.

When i asked about this to my staff,he said just use Eclipse IDE alone to do Spring Framework.

IS IT ENOUGH TO CODE SPRING MVC FRAMEWORK WITH USE OF ECLIPSE IDE OR I NEED SOME OTHER PLUGINS?

THANKS.

Comment: Using notepad and java SDK alone is enough, you don't even need eclipse (although it'll make your life much easier). Also asking your question in all caps is often treated as impolite -- it has the equivalent of yelling in real life

Answer (score 0):

I would say even a simple notepad++ should be enough for Spring MVC. For normal use I would suggest Eclipse IDE. You need to download the spring framework jar's though.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplerr) is powerful and enough.

if you have a lot of time, using [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplerr) is also ok.

Plugins just speed up your development process, but not essential.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Tool suite.
This is the best IDE which can be there for Spring . Because it comes from Spring source itself

http://www.springsource.org/sts

Otherwise there are commercial IDEs like MyEclipse which also gives good support for Spring, Struts etc.

cheers,
Saurav